# How to run part of my nodejs code on the client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm running a nodejs server based using the example [here](http://runnable.com/U0sU598vXio2uD-1/example-reading-form-input-with-express-4-0-and-body-parser-for-node-js):

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser());
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  var html = '<form action="/" method="post">' +
               'Enter your name:' +
               '<input type="text" name="number1" >' +
               '<br>' +
               '<input type="text" name="number2" >' +
               '<br>' +
               '<button type="submit">Submit</button>' +
            '</form>';

  res.send(html);
});

app.post('/', function(req, res){
  var number1 = req.body.number1;
  var number2 = req.body.number2;
  var result = eval(number1+'+'+number2)
  var html = result + '.<br>' +
             '<a href="/">Try again.</a>';
  res.send(html);
});

app.listen(80);
```

Is there any way that for example if I perform some calculations inside the `app.post` function they run on the client side and not on the server side?

Comment: No, you’d have to write some client-side JavaScript. Node.js doesn’t really change anything about that model.

Comment: Your node server runs on your machine because NodeJs is installed on it.

Comment: can't I send a nodejs file to run on the client browser console and send me back results?

Comment: It can’t use Node.js features at that point. You can send environment-agnostic code, if you like – I don’t think it’s worth the hassle, but some frameworks try to make it work.

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371196/node-js-and-client-sharing-the-same-scripts what you want to do?